# Why would modinfo say a module is not found when it appears with lsmod

Tags: modules

I have noticed several cases where, if I use `lsmod` to find a module and then use `modinfo` for that module, it comes out with a **ERROR: Module not found** message. For example with the Nvidia module (When using the proprietary drivers).

So in what cases would a module appear on `lsmod` but give an ERROR like the one I mentioned above with `modinfo`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's being aliased. In my example (similar to yours perhaps):

```
lsmod | grep nvidia
nvidia               9171294  51

modinfo nvidia
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module nvidia

modprobe --resolve-alias nvidia
nvidia_current

grep -r nvidia /etc/modprobe.d/
/etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-graphics-drivers.conf:alias nvidia nvidia_current

modinfo nvidia_current
filename:       /lib/modules/3.7.5-030705-generic/updates/dkms/nvidia_current.ko
alias:          char-major-195-*
version:        313.09
[...]
```

Above should speak for itself, doesn't it?

Comment: Above speaks for itself ^^. Is there any other case where this could also happen.

Comment: @LuisAlvarado Perhaps, but this is the only one I know of.

Comment: So if I have `alias myModuleAlias someModule`, does `modinfo myModuleAlias` not work? I would have expected this to be part of the point of an alias?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to run:

```
depmod -a
```